# RestKit: Problems mapping complex nesting, multiple levels needing forceCollectionMapping

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapping, restkit

I'm trying to map some JSON data with RestKit, and have so far been unable to do it right.
The data is a hierarchical set of days and registrations. It looks like the following (not a possibility for me to change it):

```
{
  "days": 
  {
    "2012-10-29": {
        "2106303": {
            "activityCode": "LU",
            "approved": false,
            "hours": 0.5,
            "description": "some description",
        },
        "2106304": {
            "activityCode": "VF",
            "approved": false,
            "hours": 7.5,
            "description": "some other description",
        }
        },
        "2012-10-30": null,
  }
}
```

My code looks like the following:

```
- (void)setupWeekMappingForManager:(RKObjectManager *)manager
{
    RKObjectMapping *registrationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Registration class]];
    registrationMapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
    [registrationMapping mapKeyOfNestedDictionaryToAttribute:@"registrationNumber"];

    RKObjectMapping *dayMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Day class]];
    dayMapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
    [dayMapping mapKeyOfNestedDictionaryToAttribute:@"date"];

    // how can this relationship be mapped?
    [dayMapping mapKeyPath:@"(date)." toRelationship:@"registrations" withMapping:registrationMapping]; 

    [manager.mappingProvider setMapping:dayMapping forKeyPath:@"days"];
}
```

It happily returns the days, but I am unable to find a good way to map the relationship between the two types,

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated,

Best Regards,
Tommy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
- (void)setupWeekMappingForManager:(RKObjectManager *)manager
{
    RKObjectMapping *registrationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Registration class]];
    registrationMapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
    [registrationMapping mapKeyOfNestedDictionaryToAttribute:@"registrationNumber"];
    [registrationMapping mapKeyPath:@"(registrationNumber).description" toAttribute:@"description"];

    RKObjectMapping *dayMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Day class]];
    dayMapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
    [dayMapping mapKeyOfNestedDictionaryToAttribute:@"date"];
    [dayMapping mapKeyPath:@"(date)" toRelationship:@"registrations" withMapping:registrationMapping];

    [manager.mappingProvider setMapping:dayMapping forKeyPath:@"days"];
}
```

This gives me a day object with a nice array of hour registrations as an NSArray.
For reference, it looks like this:

```
@interface Day : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSMutableArray *registrations;
@end
```